# $3$ sons that must sell in the same price

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

> A father send his $3$ sons to sell watermelons.The first son took $10$
>   watermelons,the second $20$ and the third $30$ watermelons.The father
>   gave order to sell all in the same price and collect and the same
>   number of money.How is this possible?

Any ideas for this puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

Son 3 sells 30 watermelons, then buys 20 watermelons from Son 2.
Son 2 buys 10 watermelons from Son 1.

Comment: So, the sons come back home with watermelons ? Because, I think that they could iterate according to your process. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I don't think my solution can be iterated because Son1 can't join in.  But perhaps Son 3 could give ten watermelons to Son 1 because they are all in the same firm; then each sell twenty watermelons.

Answer (score 1):

We can model this as:
$$
10 p = 20 p = 30 p \Rightarrow
$$
Subtracting $10 p$ from both sides of the first equation gives
$$
0 = 10 p \Rightarrow \\
p = 0
$$

Comment: Good deal for the customer !

Comment: Bad spec by the dad.

Comment: This what he wanted, no ? Cheers

Comment: we can think maybe that second and third son could sell the same number of watermelons like the first so we have same number of money?

Answer (score 0):

Son 3 sells 20 watermelons then gives 10 watermelons to son 1. Son 2 and son 1 then sell 20 watermelons each.

Comment: I added this answer to emphasize that the problem is not specified enough. We must infer the actions of the acting entities from some common background knowledge. We could introduce extra actors etc. etc.